# Count only one record pr day

Tags: sql-server

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM dbo.dutyrostershift 
WHERE employeeid = 1931 
  AND DATO BETWEEN '20210901' AND '20220831' 
  AND shifttype IN (0,1,4,5,6,15,16,20)
```

In short it asks about how many jobs one employee has got of some types of work in a given period.

It's used for counting days with work.

Which means, that if there is two or more records with the same date, it should only count 1 for that day.

Comment: `CAST` the date (and time?) column to a `date` and `COUNT` the `DISTINCT` values of that expression.

Comment: Side point: `WHERE dateWithTime BETWEEN dateWithoutTime AND dateWithoutTime` probably doesn't do what you think it does. See https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 2):

Instead of counting the rows, count the distinct dates in that period. ie:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct cast(dato as date))  
FROM dbo.dutyrostershift 
WHERE employeeid = 1931 AND 
     DATO BETWEEN '20210901' AND '20220831' AND 
     shifttype IN (0,1,4,5,6,15,16,20);
```